# Set in intellij the root indent to 0

Tags: intellij-idea, formatting, indentation

I am using intellij and i want to set the root indent to 0, but the normal indent to 2. Is there a way in intellij to do that?

Actual:

[image: Actual]

Target:

[image: Target]

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding 'script' to `Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML > Other > Do no indent children of`.